# Showing that a function is not analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $$h(z) = |\exp (z^3(z-1))|, z\in\mathbb{C}$$

Show that for every domain $D\subset\mathbb{C}$ the function $h(z)$ is **not** analytic in $D$.

I have no idea where to begin. Do I use Cauchy-Riemann? Calculating partial derivatives of $h(z)$ seems like a headache.

Comment: Do you know that Cauchy Riemann equations are equivalent to $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}=0$

Comment: $z\mapsto |z|$ is not even differentiable so your function cannot be analytic.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I suppose that you meant “unless it is constant”.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy so, if $f(z) = u + iv$ where $v = 0$, then $u$ has to be constant for C-R to be fulfilled. With that proof, I can then deduct that my function cannot be analytic since it is real-valued but not constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the suggestion by Kai Rama Murthy, let $f:D\subset \mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ be a function such that $f(D)\subset \mathbb R$ and $f$ is analytic. Write $f=u+iv$ with $v=0$. Then, by Cauchy-Riemann,
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=0,$$ thus $u$ and hence $f$ is a constant. Consequently any analytic function taking values in $\mathbb R$ only is constant.

Now assume your function $h$ were analytic. Then it is easy to find to values $z_1,z_2$ such that $h(z_1)\neq h(z_2)$ and this gives a contradiction.